# Detecting multiple QR codes with ZXing for javascript form camera

Tags: camera, qr-code, zxing, webassembly

I'm using the code here: https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/html5-barcode-reader-javascript-webassembly.html to detect QR codes from camera. Everything is fine with a single QR code, but I want to be able to detect multiple QR codes so I change the code `ZXing._decode_qr(decodePtr);` to `ZXing._decode_qr_multi(decodePtr);` without success, it seems it detects only the first seen QR code.

That's weird because if instead I load (like here: https://github.com/yushulx/zxing-cpp-emscripten) an image with multiple QR codes and call `ZXing._decode_qr_multi(decodePtr);`, all QR codes are detected.

Can you help me, please?
TIA

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
The camera resolution was too low. Increasing the resolution fixed everything